# Word or phrase for mere coincidence that brings happiness

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, formality, business-language

I wish to state that my exposure to a certain area was a mere coincidence, and I am happy about the area.   Moreover, I want to convey the idea that the incident was like a fairytale, something no one would easily believe, but because of it I ended up where I am.  The same incident happening to someone else might go unnoticed but it rang the bells for me.

Stating this idea as above is too long and boring, and such language seems childish or out-of-place in a statement of purpose. I want to make it succinct.  Is there any word or phrase that conveys the same idea?

Comment: I think it might help to give an actual concrete example.

Comment: Changing the title of this question to include the word "serendipitous" made it hard for me to understand why the question was being asked – until I realized that word was included only as part of a later edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your exposure to (whatever) was "serendipitous" which while by definition may be about "luck", if you were not prepared for it, opportunity could have easily passed you by.

> From Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary:
>
> ***Serendipitous***: obtained or characterized by serendipity, ex.:***serendipitous discoveries***
>
> Definition of ***"serendipity"*** from Dictionary.com:
>
> ser·en·dip·i·ty  [ser-uh n-dip-i-tee]
>
> noun
>
> 1. an aptitude for making desirable discoveries by accident.
> 2. good fortune; luck: the serendipity of getting the first job she applied for.

Answer (score 0):

A "happy coincidence" might do it.