# A situation where the adjective being used to describe the noun is actually the opposite of the adjective being used

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, antonyms

Forgive me, for I am not very eloquent.

If someone were to tell a bad joke  but in the given scenario it got some laughs and could be recounted as a “good joke” then the joke was _____.

On the surface and out of context, the object of the sentence (in this case the joke) was bad, but in the given situation it was actually good, what would be a word to describe that?

When something could be described as one thing, but in a certain situation it is exactly the opposite. It would be _____.

Comment: You could say the joke "worked."

Comment: I'm not sure why there are votes to close this question; I'm voting to keep it open. It asks a reasonable question, provides adequate detail, and includes two useful sentences to demonstrate how the word or phrase might be used. If anyone thinks this question is below par, please [edit] it to provide the necessary improvements. Accelerating your VTC score without taking the care to assess each question properly undermines the value of our review queue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word or phrase for mere coincidence that brings happiness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96583/word-or-phrase-for-mere-coincidence-that-brings-happiness) Answers include 'happy coincidence' and 'serendipitous'.

Answer (score 1):

How about **ben trovato**?

> appropriate and characteristic even if untrue; happily invented or discovered.

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 0):

The joke was *successful* in that it got a laugh. It was great, fantastic. But if it offended some then it was thoughtless and in bad taste.

Humour usually makes a bad example of anything. When a joke is bad it can go over very well. There are too many levels of success and failure to use it reliably. A joke that was not expected to get a laugh could make a needed and touching point of the situation.  In fact the most popular jokes are 'bad' since they reflect a point of view, pun or connection that was too base to point out yet clever and not yet discovered.

Please find another example and I will edit to put in an answer since I ain't got one.

Comment: Take Capital Gains Tax for example. To a very rich person who makes most of their income through capital gains, the taxation rate (Maximum 20% with a 3.8% kicker over a Certain threshold)  could be seen as fair and a good thing. 

But to someone who makes mostly wages, and finds themselves paying a higher effective rate (24% and up) on their income, the capital gains tax could be seen as unfair and a bad thing. Then the capital gains tax could be described as _______? 

When something is true to one person and at the very same time untrue to another person, that something is ______?

Comment: Would it be subjective?

Comment: After revisiting this, I feel like my examples are comparing apples to oranges. 

I still am curious as to what people in this forum think might be the correct term to describe the situations I’ve brought up.

Comment: The technical term might be Counter-intuitive. But would surely be more dependent of ones perspective.